# Laravel postgres Distinct ON query builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to make this query the most Laravel way possible by using the query builder.
Thanks

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (spaceid) * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (galleryid) * FROM gallery_spaces ORDER BY galleryid, RANDOM()) AS intermediate ORDER BY spaceid, RANDOM() LIMIT 8
```

Sorry, this is as close as I can get, but it's not the same

```
  $diferentsGalleries = GallerySpace::select(DB::raw('DISTINCT ON(galleryid) *'))
                                    ->wherehas('gallery')
                                    ->orderByRaw('galleryid, RANDOM()')
                                    ->limit(30)
                                    ->pluck('id');

  $featured_spaces = GallerySpace::select(DB::raw('DISTINCT ON(spaceid) *'))
                                ->with('space')
                                ->with('gallery')
                                ->wherein('id',$diferentsGalleries)
                                ->orderByRaw('spaceid, RANDOM()')
                                ->limit(8)
                                ->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What specific issue are you facing? Stackoverflow is not a free coding service; you're expected to make an effort to solve your own issue before asking for help.

Comment: > Sorry, this is as close as I can get, but it's not the same ... @Gatis do you know that you dd/dump you query to see the sal generated https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#debugging ... That said I really thing raw sql is more elegant for such cases and since Laravel will retrasform in raw sql what's the advatage ... except learning.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure it out.

```
$featured_spaces = GallerySpace::select(DB::raw('DISTINCT ON (spaceid) *'))
                                  ->fromSub(function ($query) {
                                            $query->from('gallery_spaces')
                                                  ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT ON (galleryid) *'))
                                                  ->orderby('galleryid')
                                                  ->inrandomorder();}, 'intermediate')
                                  ->orderby('spaceid')
                                  ->inrandomorder()
                                  ->limit(8)     
                                  ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel offers many ways, none are better than others, having your query the easiet way is to use db facade

```
$result=DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT ON (spaceid) * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (galleryid) * FROM gallery_spaces ORDER BY galleryid, RANDOM()) AS intermediate ORDER BY spaceid, RANDOM() LIMIT 8");
```

Comment: Preface; wasn't my downvote, but I can understand why it would receive one. Also votes are anonymous for many reasons. Now, while this answer "works", it doesn't even attempt to make use of Laravel's Eloquent or Query Builder functions: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries. Additionally, it's best to wait for follow-ups to requests for clarification (see my comment on the original question) before providing an answer.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis for reply. I saw your comment but really neither you and me know the knowledge of the person who wrote OP and my answer is here also to clarify "Laravel way". No need to go to query builder or Eloquent in this case and furthermore it's tiùe consuming (codig & CPU since Laravel will rettransforms the queru in SQL)! Still waiting for the person who downvote explain why and give a better solution :-)

Comment: You might be waiting for a while; voters aren't notified by your comment asking them to explain their vote. But that's neither here not there, downvotes happen  One correction with your answer; using `DB::select()` here is wrong, should be `DB::statement()`, and that command is not SQL-agnostic, meaning it will only work in Postgres (which is fine, but Eloquent and the Builder will adapt, meaning it can work for Postgres, MySQL, etc). They really are the better options, and you should encourage using them when possible (there are situations where you need to use `DB::raw()` for example).

Comment: Ok for DB::statement but that does not mean that DB::select is wrong! Ok also for the other points, I gave previously  the avantages of my answer and you gave the disadvantages. As I wrote, Laravel offers any way to do the job and like everything there pro & con for each one.

Comment: Woops, sorry, I have it backwards; `DB::statement` is wrong, `DB::select` is right; disregard that part. And that's exactly it; there's pros and cons, and someone saw more cons with your answer, hence the downvote. Maybe they'll chime in, or maybe you'll try to solve it with the Query Builder and update your answer, who knows. But regardless, this is how Stackoverflow works; the community decides on what quality answers are by the voting system.

Comment: You are right DB::statement is wrong in this case, the beginning of my previous answer is wrong too. That said the vote of a very few (1 to 3) number of people is not democratic and it's not "the community" ... but it's the (actual) rules and we need rules.